# Guice Null pointer error on Injected Class

Tags: java, playframework, guice

i am using guice with java play framework.

i have a simple command interface, and a implementor created in java like this:

```
public interface ICommand {
public void test();
}
```

And the implementor

```
public class CommandImpl implements ICommand {
@Override
public void test() {
System.out.println("test");
}
```

And then the binding class for @Inject:

```
public class ICommandModule extends AbstractModule{
@Override
protected void configure() {
bind(ICommand.class).to(CommandImpl.class);
}
}
```

When i try the command like this:

```
@Inject
private static ICommand Command;
public static void index() {
Command.test();
render();
}
```

i get these errors:

From Web Browser:

```
Execution exception
NullPointerException occured : null
```

From the Console:

```
Execution exception (In /app/controllers/Application.java around line 27) NullPointerException occured : null
play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException  
  at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:231)  
  at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!) 
Caused by: 
java.lang.NullPointerException  
  at controllers.Application.index(Application.java:27)     
  at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:548)  
  at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:502)  
  at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:478)  
  at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:473)  
  at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:161)  ... 1 more
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: The NPE occurs in `app.controllers.Application` - do you have the relevant code at hand?

Comment: well the controller.Application code is the one with @inject.. are you asking that or am i getting your questoin wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `static`. `Inject` works only on instance variable and constructors.
You need to use `requestStaticInjection` in your module.

Comment: I've realized that you are right, the injection doesnt work with static voids. Thanks for the information. But i didnt understand how to use requeststaticInjection, can you explain this to me more please?

Comment: In your module, in the `configure()` method, you can invoke `requestStaticInjection(YourClassThatNeedsStaticInjection.class)`. I have never tried it though but it is its purpose. But you should ask yourself if you could not avoid this static variable, using for example a Singleton

Comment: The answer is not correct. Guice module does work with static members.

Comment: This is absolutely false. Take a look at here: http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Injections#Static_Injections

Comment: This is absolutely true. I am not talking about google-guice itself, I am talking about the play module built on google-guice. I am the contributor of this module, I know exactly what it does. Check http://www.playframework.org/modules/guice-1.2/home

Answer (score 0):

Are you using guice module from http://www.playframework.org/modules/guice ? That one should be work with static field injection.

Comment: why down vote here? Please make sure you understand exactly before doing negative vote